# Как конкатинировать и отформатировать вывод postgres

Tags: postgresql

Знаю что спрашивали не однократно, но ответ найти не могу, ребята, подскажите.

У меня есть три таблицы

```
students (student_id, first_name, last_name);
courses (course_id, name, description);
students_courses (student_id, course_id);
```

Задача

> Write SQL query that finds name of course and related students.

Я написал запрос

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, c.name 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN students_courses sc ON sc.course_id = c.course_id 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.student_id = sc.student_id 
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Который выводит таблицу в таком виде

```
 name | first_name |  last_name   
 ------+------------+--------------
 Java | Name       | SurName
 Java | Name       | SurName
 Java | Name       | SurName
 Java | Name       | SurName
 JS   | Name       | SurName
 JS   | Name       | SurName
 ...
```

А мне нужен такой вывод:

```
 course_name | full_name   
 ------+------------+--------------
 Java        | Name Surname1, Name Surname2, Name Surname3...
 JS          | Name Surname1, Name Surname2, Name Surname3...
```

Тоесть вывод через запятую в части где имена.
А также вывод названия курса в виде DISTINCT.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [concat](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/concat-function.php).

```
SELECT concat(s.first_name,', ', s.last_name) "full_name", c.name 
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN students_courses sc ON sc.course_id = c.course_id 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.student_id = sc.student_id 
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли.

Сделал в итоге так 

`SELECT c.name AS course_name, string_agg(concat(s.first_name,' ', s.last_name), ', ') "full_name"
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN students_courses sc ON sc.course_id = c.course_id 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.student_id = sc.student_id 
GROUP BY c.name;`